# how to await completion of redux dispatch call

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await

I dispatch an action from my code to login, which contains an API request to login and set the currentUser variable in my store. Immediately after the dispatch I would like to check if the currentUser is set, however since the dispatch is asynchronous, the if condition reads current user as "" first and I have to trigger the event twice for the currentUser variable to be read with the expected data. I tried using async-await but the problem persists. How can I make the dispatch complete before moving onto the next line?

Where I dispatch from:

```
async function handleSubmit() {
  const details = {
    "username": userName,
    "password": password
  }
  await props.login( details ) ### This is the dispatch ###
  if ( props.currentUser !== "" ) props.handleAuthentication()
}
```

This is my action I am calling in the dispatch:

```
export function login( details ) {
    const url = 'user/login'
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify( details )
    };
    return ( dispatch ) => {
    return fetchReq( requestOptions, url ).then( ([response]) => {
        if( response.status === RESPONSE.OK ){
          dispatch( loginSuccess(details.username) )
      }
      else{
        dispatch( loginError() )
      }
    } )
  }
}
```

Helper Function for above action:

```
export function fetchReq( options, endpoint ) {
  const url = 'api/' + endpoint
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then( response => Promise.all([response, response.json()]));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use react's lifecycle for handling changes at your redux state, which should be mapped to props. `componentDidUpdate` for classic react would do the trick. if you are using hooks, `useEffect` passing as second argument `[props.currentUser]` which is the value you want to track.